# C++17 in a package with Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

```
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::plugins("cpp17")]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double rcpp_hello_world(Rcpp::NumericVector x) {
  
  double z;
  z = std::cyl_bessel_i(0, x[0]);
  return z ;
}
```

When I run the above code and call it using `sourceCpp`, it works as expected. However inside a R package setup I get

```
error: cyl_bessel_iis not a member of ‘std
      11 |         z = std::cyl_bessel_i[0]);
         |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
   make: *** [/usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf:177: rcpp_hello_world.o] Error 1
   ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Package’
```

upon running `Rcpp::compileAttributes()` and `devtools::document()`. I initialised the package with `Rcpp.package.skeleton`.

`cyl_bessel_i` was added to the standard library in C++17.

I am using `gcc-12.1.0-2` and `R-4.2.0-3`. I am on Arch Linux.

Comment: Do you have `CXX_STD=CXX17` in your `src/Makevars` file?  I don't know `Rcpp` well, but I'd expect it to use `cxx17`, not `cpp17`.

Comment: @user2554330 Thank you. Adding `CXX_STD=CXX17` to `src/Makevars` solved it for me. `// [[Rcpp::plugins("cpp17")]]` seems redundant now and compiles without it also. I am on `Rcpp 1.0.9` and it is suggested in the [official documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-package.pdf) that `Makevars` is optional.

Comment: Adding `SystemRequirements: C++17` in `DESCRIPTION` seems to also work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default C++ standard used in current versions of R is C++11 (or C++14 if available).  Since you require C++17, you need to declare it in the `src/Makevars` file, using the line

```
CXX_STD=CXX17
```

In a comment you referred to the [`Rcpp` documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-package.pdf) which says that `Makevars` is optional since `Rcpp` 0.11.0.  I think that was written about linking to the `Rcpp` libs, but it is also true here, as pointed out by @MikkoMarttila:  you can alternatively declare the C++ version in the `SystemRequirements:` field of the `DESCRIPTION` file, e.g.

```
SystemRequirements: C++17
```